# Найти значение в масиве которое встречается наибольшее количество раз

Tags: c++

Мой  код, как я мог сделать. Но нужна ваша помощь

```
int count = 0;
for (std::size_t i = 1; i < array.size(); ++i) 
{
    if (array[i] == count)
        ++count;
    else
        count = 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваш код имеет мало отношения к задаче... Я даже затрудняюсь сказать, что именно он считает...

Comment: @zcorvid я  беру  значения  и сравниваю его с значением в масиве, если однаковы  тогда я +1  делаю

Comment: @dimaAf И что считается таким образом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Вариант через std::map:

```
std::map<int, int> mp;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i) 
{
    ++mp[array[i]];
}

int curr_num = mp.begin()->first;
int curr_max = mp.begin()->second;
for (auto it = mp.begin(); it != mp.end(); ++it)
{
    if (it->second > curr_max)
    {
        curr_num = it->first;
        curr_max = it->second;
    }
}

std::cout << curr_num << " " << curr_max << std::endl;
```

PS. Код в компиляторе не проверял, но идея должна быть понятна, даже если я где-то ошибся.

Answer (score 3):

Создайте `std::unordered_map<ArrayElementType, std::size_t> map`. Пройдите по массиву, заполнив карту методом `map[array[i]] += 1`. В итоге в ней будет частоты встречаемости всех встреченных в массиве символов. Потом легко найти нужный элемент одним проходом по карте.